# Have private betas in "Your Communities" list in the Stack Exchange dropdown

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button, private-beta, communities-list

Whenever you have signed into a private beta, could it please appear in the drop down something like this:

[image]

So here the number means I have 2 Private Beta Communities, and the arrow is clickable so that you can access all of them. This would keep it relatively unobtrusive and make it much easier to access all of them.

Comment: This is a manually managed list - simply add it yourself. I sometimes join private beta just to have a look and never come back.

Comment: Hmm... that said, private beta doesn't appear in the "more stack exchange communities" search box - so I'll support feature request asking to add them when searching.

Comment: You can add when you edit them. Maybe add PBs you committed to?

Comment: hmm... makes more sense,  but still don't feel comfortable auto adding to a manual list.

Comment: I was a little unsure about it too, which is why I went for the grouped option... Still not sure about it but still...

Comment: Turns out that when editing the list they do appear when adding - so it's easy to add them to the customized list.

Comment: I just add them manually using the "edit" button... works great.