# Can we add private betas in "your communities" drop down?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-button, private-beta, communities-list

I am actively participating in a few graduated sites and a private beta. What I normally do when I become active somewhere is to add the site into my "your communities" list dropdown.

However, I noticed that it is not possible to add sites in your own "Your communities" if they are -still- in private beta.

Could we have this option?

<sub>Note this is pretty related to [Have private betas in "Your Communities" list in the Stack Exchange dropdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253374/209901) and what was then mentioned in comments there, but wanted to make sure it is requested in a stand alone post, since in that post they are asking for something more generic.</sub>

Comment: I had the `Hardware Recommendations` site in the drop-down list from like it's second day of graduation (into private beta).  So, I think you can manually add them.

Comment: @Dawny33 I am trying to add [Spanish Stack Overflow](http://es.stackoverflow.com/) but it does not show when I look for it :/

Comment: Yeah, it didn't.  I tried to add it, and it didn't appear on the list.  But, I can swear that I had the HW Recs site.  Not sure what's the problem here!

Comment: @Dawny33 wow I just noticed it does work. You cannot find it, but if you click in -edit- then you can find it.

Comment: Ha ha  yeah.  It did work for me.  I just had too many in the pinned list, so that wasn't showing up :D

Comment: The only private beta at the moment is [Stack Overflow in Spanish](http://es.stackoverflow.com/) and it's not showing when searching the list, however it does show in the drop down when trying to add - so it's not different than adding any other site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add private beta sites in the pinned list in the drop-down list of sites same way you can add any other site. (They don't appear in the ordinary search, but do appear when adding)

All you have to do it is go to the edit button, search for it, select the site you want to add, and then click add; and you can see the site in the drop-down.

> [image]

The resulting list would look like this.

Comment: Neither of those are in private beta. They are both public beta.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I guess it is a misunderstanding by Dawny. The one I was referring to is [Stack Overflow in Spanish](http://es.stackoverflow.com/) and his workaround works.

Comment: @fedorqui in this case, your question makes no sense. We could add those from the very beginning

Comment: @ShadowWizard you are right, I had not checked this properly. We may want to add yet another question around this topic asking for such private betas to be "searcheable" in the dropdown. Also, I am editing my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @ShadowWizard  I would be deleting the answer, if unaccepted :)

Comment: No need to delete anymore, I've edited out the wrong parts. :)